# Is my HHD dying?

Tags: hard-drive

I'm asking this because my HDD (Hard Disk) has 5 years, and ultimately (this year) it gave me many headaches. Many moths ago I has Windows 7 (and 10 T.P. since april) and all was good. But after a moment, instantly, all gets reversed: *veeery* slow, and actions which will take a tiny time, at these moment the time seems frozen (for example, instead a 1 minute boot, it turned to 5-8 minutes boot). I formatted and installed Windows every 2 months because it was the time which runs good before it gets *slooww*. Seeing the abuse of privacity in W10, I changed to Ubuntu 15.04 and the things lasted more in time... But again, HDD error.
Click, trying to read, click, trying to read... And the upper bar (title of window/buttons of volume, language, wifi, etc.) disappeared. The left bar (where are the app's icons) was empty and the file explorer said the resource wasn't available (or something like these error). I restarted and nothing happens. I had to press CTRL+D to boot-up Ubuntu, but after hours... the same error (can't do anything except moving the mouse/cursor).

Welcome to the routine: copy files with live-cd to a pendrive, wipe HDD and install all again.
And the things was calmed again... and the errors comes again.
And after 2 weeks, I had to do the same. Now my PC works fine, but yesterday I heard a few "*clicks*" from the HDD.

Now, I remembered this  and I came to Disks and the HDD shows a new value; normally, the problematic number was "*pending sectors*", always changing, but now, in "*irrecoverable sectors*", the number is different of zero.

I never had "*reallocated sectors*". Now, neither. And now, while I write this lines, I've 5 "*pending s.*" and 9 "*irrecoverable s.*". If this helps, the "read error rate" is 42, 5 for "*write error rate*".

> Very well!! While I was writing *"write error rate"*, I heard 2
>   clicks. And while writing this, one click more.

And 123 "CRC error rate".
So, with this information: is my HDD dying? It'll last days or months?
I think this problem will kill the disk in a not very far time.

The drive is a *Western Digital Green 1TB-WDC WD10EARS-00Y5B1 (80.00A80)*
S.N.: *WD-WCAV5J301610*

PS: When I boot with CTRL+D, many times the system is in "*RO mode*"; I can't save/download files, Unity doesn't find apps when I write their name *{click again, now, while I write the text}* and, after a few hours, a crash like the lines above

Comment: Yes. get your data off now, and get a new one.

Comment: @Mateo I suspected it. Someday this had to occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it bluntly, yes. Your HDD is dying. As sectors on the drive start to fail, the drive automatically starts to remap sectors to minimize data loss. These are the reallocated sectors.

Pending sectors are waiting to be remapped. If the sector has a successful read or write attempt while pending, it will not be remapped, and removed from pending. It will only be remapped on a write failure.

Uncorrectable sectors are sectors in the hard drive that cannot be read or written to, indicating a failing hard drive.

The clicks you hear can be caused by many things, but it all comes down to the internals being worn out.

Comment: Now I've got a new HDD, so the problem is solved. I hope this HDD lasts as minimum other 5 years. Thanks to you by your information.